# Why does "$this->_query->execute()" always evaluate as false?

Tags: php, mysql, object, pdo

I have, in a db.php file, the following code:

```
    public function query($sql, $params = array()){
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)){
            foreach($params AS $pa){
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $pa);
                $x++;
            }
        }
        #MASSIVE ERROR
        #correctthis
        if($this->_query->execute()){
            echo 'success';
            $this->_result = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_query = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

public function error(){
    return $this->_error;
}
```

My problem is that `$this->_query->execute()` always is false, which means $_error is always being set to true. I can't get it to work, even though there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it.

The script enters the prepare (I tested by echoing), which means it prepared successfully. It also enters the foreach loop so the values must be getting bound. But it just can't seem to execute. Why?

Edit:

I use `DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT email FROM user_credentials WHERE user_id = ?", array(1))` to call the query, and this is what getInstance looks like:

```
    public static function getInstance(){
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
        self::$_instance = new DB();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}
```

Comment: How does your **$sql** statement look like? Does it expect params your are not providing in the execute?

Comment: I'm using `DB::getInstance()->query("SELECT email FROM user_credentials WHERE user_id = ?", array(1));` and I'm editing my post to show what getInstance looks like.

Comment: for the question mark you do not need bind params, but either way you should provide the param in the execute call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your function this way

```
public function queryAll($sql, $params = array(), $method = PDO::FETCH_OBJ)
{
    $stmt = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt->fetchAll($method);
}
```

or, if you prefer method chaining, then this way

```
public function query($sql, $params = array())
{
    $stmt = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt;
}
```

Then set PDO in exception mode, and you will be always informed of any error occurred. To so so add this code in constructor

```
$this->_pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

The rest of your code is useless, inflexible, error-prone and sometimes plainly wrong.

Comment: Thank you! But what happens to your code when '$params' has no elements? Also, why do you suggest using '$stmt' instead of '$this->_query'?

Comment: I dont know who downvoted you, but this answer is helpful. I'm only just starting out on PDO, this code was from a tutorial, so you see what's happening to the data step by step.

Comment: @markovchain just try it and see. Nothing particular though - query just got executed as usual.

Comment: @markovchain `$method = PDO::FETCH_OBJ` is default value for function [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not properly connected with the database. See if the connecting function is working properly. Something like the code below if you are trying this from an online tutorial:

```
$this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get 
('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), 
Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this to know the specific error returned by the query. I have only modified the **else** block.

```
    #MASSIVE ERROR
    #correctthis
    if($this->_query->execute()){
        echo 'success';
        $this->_result = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $this->_query = $this->_query->rowCount();
    } else {
        $this->_error = true;
        echo $this->_query->errorInfo()[2];
    }
```